# How to know how many smoothing groups i have in my model?

Tags: normal-map

I'm having trouble with normal map in substance painter, so to not separate the uv based on my hard edges, its probably better to make only one smoothing group.

Avoiding this boring process. however i can't find how many smoothing groups i got on my model.

Comment: Zero, Blender doesn't have any "smoothing groups"

Comment: It has. At least blender 2.8